# RichTextBox TextChanged not fired

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, tabcontrol

I have a RichTextBox which is in a page of my TabControl. Take notice that the RichTextBox is programmaticaly made with the following code:

```
TabPage addedTabPage = new TabPage("Tab Page");
tabControl.TabPages.Add(addedTabPage);

RichTextBox addedRichTextBox = new RichTextBox()
{
    Parent = addedTabPage,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    /* ... */
};
```

Moreover, at the beginning of each of my methods I use this code in order to have access to my RichTextBox:

```
RichTextBox programTextBox = 
    (RichTextBox)tabControl.TabPages[tabControl.SelectedIndex].Controls[0];
```

Everything in my program seems to work fine, but I've noticed that the Text_Changed event is never fired. Why does that happen and how can make this event fire (preferably by its own as it does in a simple RichTextBox).

Comment: Are you assigning a method to the event?

Comment: When I first made my program, the RichTextBox was a simple, no TabControls and I used the `private void programTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`. When I decided to add the TabControl and put the RichTextBox inside it, I did not change the event at all, but now it does nothing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    addedRichTextBox.TextChanged += addedRichTextBox_TextChanged;        

    void addedRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Text changed");
    }
```